# How to handle single selection in uicollectionview in iphone

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (shareEnabled)
{
    // Determine the selected items by using the indexPath
    NSString *selectedRecipe = [self.getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Add the selected item into the array
    [getImage addObject:selectedRecipe];
}
}
```

How  to handle single selection in iphone sdk. When I press on particular cell then it should be show on big view on the same view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, so it's not entirely clear what you are asking. The code you posted is adding an NSString to (presumedly) an array, but doesn't display anything.

If you want to display that string, you might create a UILabel property in the same superview and set the text in this manner:

```
self.myLabel.text = selectedRecipe;
```

You could show/hide the label based on its contents, animate it into place, etc. as desired. You could have it (or a UIView that contains it) cover the collection view, etc. It really depends on how you want it presented.

Now, if what you want is to make sure that the collection view can only receive a single selection at a time, set its allowsMultipleSelection property to NO.

```
self.myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

If this doesn't help, please provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

The posted code doesn't really reflect a scenario of showing an image, as you are pulling a string (not an image) from an array.

Assuming you're trying to display an image in your app bundle with a given name (stored in the string), you could do so like this - assuming that the string is the file's name:

```
NSString *selectedRecipeImageFileName = [self.recipeImageFileNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // ie. "cake.jpg"

UIImage *selectedRecipeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedRecipeImageFileName];

self.recipeImageView.image = selectedRecipeImage;
```

In this case, "self.recipeImageView" would be a UIImageView that you've already added as a subview.

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, please explain in a bit more detail how you're trying to get an image from a string (and where the images are coming from) and I'll take another look.

Comment: In my array there is a image then how to show that image in bib view in the same view

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's still a bit unclear how you're getting an image (as the collection view selection is returning a string), so my answer covers the scenario of loading an image based on a file name as a string.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please provide a bit more detail on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: It work properly but i want that if i press on blank space on view then imageview should be disapear.

Comment: You should probably include these requirements in your initial question. Or, maybe, post a new question.

To do this, you could create a UITapGestureRecognizer and attach it to the underlying view. You'd then associate a selector with it that detects if the image is visible (ie. "hidden" property is set to NO) and hide it (by setting "hidden" to YES). If the image is already visible, do nothing.

You could also approximate this using a UIButton. The best method may depend on how and where you're displaying the image.